# Magento 1 tax calculation and product price showing ambiguity

Tags: magento-1.9, tax, tax-calculation

I am having a strange issue regarding tax calculation. I am using tax prices included in catalog price while adding prices and enabled this in tax calculation too. Also I want to show Ex-Tax price on my site frontend in catalog page. I enabled this too on catalog page display settings.

So the issue is its works fine for some time but then it started to causing issues. It start to include the Tax again and add this in total so price started showing wrong. When this issue occurred we generally changed any tax settings

> (like tax calculation based on field to shipping origin and it work
>   fine for few days and when issue happened again we changed back it to
>   shipping address)

and then it started calculating correctly.

I am so confused why this is happening and then resolve just changing any setting not just the **tax calculation based on** field.

Please let me know any idea or probability for this issue.

Thank you

Comment: Please let me know if any suggestion.

Comment: Please can anyone have idea about that is there reindexing run after tax settings save